# Match user routes with posts routes with and without resourcing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

I currently have a routes file as

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
  resources :users  do
  resources :posts
end
  match "posts" => "posts#main" 
  get "home/index"
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

What I would like to do now is, also show `/users/:user_id/problems/:id` as `/problems/:id`. But not sure how should I put it into routes?

Note: I do have a relationship between users and posts.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :posts
```

and

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

Thanks

UDPATE: The error I get is `Couldn't find User without an ID`

Comment: http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/9/7/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-shallow-routes try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use shallow routes in following way,

```
 resources :users, :shallow => true do |user|
  user.resources :posts
 end
```

Comment: I am using rails 3.2.X and did this `resources :users, :shallow => true do 
  resources :problems
 end` and still getting the same error.

Comment: could you please list users controller?

Comment: I dont have any. I was just using devise given routes. What kind of methods should I be having in User controller